# How to populate a drop-down list from a SQL table in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, loops, html-select

I have a table in my SQL database, and using MVC on a ASP.NET Core:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProgramVersion] (
    [ID]       INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Ver]      VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    [Released] DATETIME     NOT NULL
);
```

Very simple. I have a scaffolded Edit.cshtml file, has a form for editing a records from a different table. I just want to use the records in the ProgramVersion table to populate an HTML select input (i.e. drop down list).

1. How do I execute a simple query that gives me a result-set?
2. How do I iterate through the result-set and simply put the 'Ver' string value into the Options tags in the drop-down list?

(In PHP, this is dead simple, but C# is really frustrating me.)

Comment: `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> options = db.ProgramVersion.Select(x => new SelectListItem{ Value = x.ID.ToString(), Text = x.Ver });`

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: Yes, using Entity Framework. that looks like a good start, Stephen Muecke, but what is the Razor syntax for getting it into the HTML form?

Comment: Um...as useful as a sinlge line of code MIGHT be, you didn't mention where to put it, and I know there has to be an iterator somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you create a view model which can transfer data between your action method and view. Add 2 properties to this, one for passing the list of options needed and one for holding the selected option value

```
public class CreateVm
{
   public List<SelectListItem> Items { set;get;}
   public int SelectedItemId { set;get;}
}
```

Now in your GET action, create an object of this, load the Items properties and pass it to the view

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   var vm = new CreateVm();

   //Load the Items property by reading the ProgramVersion table data
   vm.Items = db.ProgramVersions
               .Select(x=>new SelectListItem { Value=x.Id.ToString(),
                                               Text=x.Ver} )
               .ToList();
   return View(vm);
}
```

Now in your view, which is strongly typed to this view model, you can use the `DropDownListFor` hepler method

```
@model CreateVm
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.SelectedItemId,Model.Items,"Select one")
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

You can use the same view model in your HttpPost action method as a parameter

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreatVm model)
{
   // check model.SelectedItemId
   // to do : return something
}
```

Comment: I'm sure that is a great answer, and one way of doing it, but not really what I asked, @Shyju. I want the result-set from a query, so that I can iterate through it and MANUALLY put "Ver" field from each row into HTML OPTION tags.

Comment: that linq expression will execute a query behind the scene. Are you saying you do not want to use that and want to execute a SQL query with SqlDataReader and use the result from that ?